# How to get indexOf to check for one or multiple values

Tags: javascript

I'm using google scripts and as a result, I can't use ES6 or ES5 in my HTML code. I'd like to check if a string variable might include one or multiple of the words below. The example below doesn't work. How is this suppose to write this?

`string.indexOf("Word1" || "Word2" || "Word3") > -1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a regular expression instead:

```
/Word1|Word2|Word3/.test(string)
```

Or iterate over an array of words to search for:

```
var found = false;
var arr = ['Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3']
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (string.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
// use `found` variable
```

If you want to ensure that the string doesn't contain any of those words with a regex, then continually match characters from the beginning of the string to the end while using negative lookahead for the alternated pattern:

```
^(?:(?!Word1|Word2|Word3)[\s\S])+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/FsChvB/1

But that's strange, it'd be a lot easier just to use the same test as above, and invert it.

```
var stringContainsForbiddenWords = !/Word1|Word2|Word3/.test(string)
```

Comment: Thanks. How would that look if you wanted it 'not' to include the words using regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a for loop to check each array element.

```
var array = ["test234", "test9495", "test234", "test93992", "test234"];

for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  if (array[i] == "test234") {
    document.write(i + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Polyfill 
String.prototype.includes = String.prototype.includes || function(s) {
  return this.indexOf(s) >= 0
}

// ES6:
// const strIncludes = (string, words) =>
//   words.some(w => string.includes(w))


function strIncludes(string, words) {
  return words.some(function(s) {
    return string.includes(s)
  })
}


console.log(strIncludes('hello world and goodbye', ['hi', 'hello']))
```